# How to disable Asp.Net MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Asp.Net MVC and set up SQL Server. I have a controller. I don't want to use this controller.

How do I disable a controller without deleting it?

Comment: This is a really odd question, why on earth would you want to "disable" a controller?

Comment: I want to disable the controller in the controller is connected to the plc machine. I don't want to connect the system to the machine right now.

Comment: So you mean a PLC controller, not an MVC controller?

Comment: You could say that

Answer (score 3):

You can add ignore routes in RouteConfig file

```cs
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)  
          {  
                routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");  

                routes.IgnoreRoute("Account/");  

                routes.MapRoute(  
                    name: "Default",  
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",  
                    defaults: new   
                    {  
                        controller = "Student", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional  
                    }  
                );  
            }  
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom action filter that inherits from ActionFilterAttribute where it will check if the name of the controller is exist in a key in Web.config app settings then it will handle by returning return 404 or redirect to another page whatever you like.

Then add the new custom filter annotation to the base controller or to all the controllers that you want to manage them (disable/ enable).

Answer (score 0):

here is what I did to disable one of my controller use `Policy`:
Add below code to the controller:

`[Authorize(Policy = "Disabled")]
 public class MyController : Controller`

then in startup.cs:

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
 {
    options.AddPolicy("Disabled", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Disabled"));
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to achieve this is to change the [access modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) on the controller class.

Using the basic ASP.NET MVC project that Visual Studio 2015 creates, changing the `AccountController` class from:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
```

To:

```
class AccountController : Controller
```

(i.e. Making the class private)

Results in a 404 being returned to the browser when navigating to `http://localhost:58743/Account/Register`.

Comment: First of all, OP is apparently talking about PLC controllers (a physical item of hardware). Secondly, why make it private? A private controller is pointless, so just remove the class completely. Very peculiar answer.

Comment: Ahh, perhaps they should have been a mite clearer in their question then! =) The answer is as peculiar as the question, they asked "How do I disable a controller without deleting it?", so I provided an answer that satisfies the requirement... Removing the class completely wouldn't achieve that, had the question pertained to an MVC controller,